# Dotnet 5 to 6 migration - application fails to start - How to use IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, iis, .net-6.0, .net-5

I have migrated my `web app` from `dotnet 5` to `dotnet 6`. Firstly, I updated dotnet version for all projects in solution, and then updated necessary `nuget` packages accordingly. After this, the application worked fine.

After that, I wanted to improve my `Program.cs` class, in order to get rid of `Startup.cs`. In `dotnet 5`, my `program.cs` looked like this:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        .....
        .....
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            host.Run();
            return 0;
   }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseNLog()
                .ConfigureLogging((host, loggingBuilder) =>
                {
                    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();

                    if (host.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(".\\nlog.config");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(".\\nlog.config");
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseIIS();
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

I updated this to:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.ConfigureLogging((host, loggingBuilder) =>
{
    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();

    if (host.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(".\\nlog.config");
    }
    else
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(".\\nlog.config");
    }
})
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder.UseIIS();
    //webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); --> removed this
});
```

After this change, I get error:

[image]

I suspect, I cannot use `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` anymore. So how can I configure my app to `UseIIS`?

My hosting model is "InProc", and I cannot change that.

When I tried adding `builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>()` or `builder.WebHost.UseIIS();`, but it only changed the error to:
[image]

The `Event Logs` show following two errors:

`Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/portal' with physical root 'C:\Users\zee\source\repos\Portal\Portal.Web\' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '0'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.`

`Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/portal' with physical root 'C:\Users\zee\source\repos\Portal\Portal.Web\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message: CLR worker thread exited prematurely`

The docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-6.0#get-started) says that `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` calls `Kestrel` internally. How this behavior can be changed to use `IIS` instead?
I have tried few other things, but did not work.
**Question:**
Can someone point me to the right direction? Why there is no clear guidelines on using IIS? Several answers suggest that I should change to OutOfProc, which I cannot.

Comment: Run a report to collect some basic information, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 503 error.